# chrome:headless (MacOS) results with ' 1) AssertionError: expected 'about:blank' to include $target page'

Tags: testing, cucumber, testcafe, gherkin, google-chrome-headless

I am using TestCafe in combination with gherkinTestcafe (steps) / cucumber.
I am also using environment variables so that i can run my tests on 2 different environments.

My code is as follows, although through debugging, i don't believe this is something strictly code related, as much as it is related to:

- chrome:headless
- environment
- version of chrome / MacOS

```
import Enviorments from "../../../../../../AEM_Engine/Enviorment/Enviorments";
import { Helper } from "../../../../../TestActions/Test_specific/Career_helper";
import {AddAuthCredentialsHook} from "../../../../../TestActions/BasicAuth";

const {Before, Given, Then} = require('cucumber');
let publisher = new Publish();
let aemEnv = new Enviorments();
let helper = new Helper;

let careersPage = '/career';

Before('@basicAuth', async testController => {
    const addAuthCredentialsHook = new AddAuthCredentialsHook('$someUserName', '$somePassword');
    await testController.addRequestHooks(addAuthCredentialsHook);
});

Before('@disableCookie', async testController => {
    await testController.addRequestHooks(publisher.mockCookieResponse);
});

Given('I am at Careers page', async testController => {
    await publisher.Navigate(testController, aemEnv.frontEndURL + careersPage);
    await publisher.verifyURL(testController, aemEnv.frontEndURL + careersPage);
});

.
.
.
```

When i wait for the script to run i have

```
 1) AssertionError: expected 'about:blank' to include $expectedPage
```

As i mentioned, i don't believe the problem is in the code. Even if i remove the step for verifying the current URL location, the test fails on the next step after.
Tests pass on

- Chrome (with UI shell)
- Other browsers (firefox, safari), headless or with UI shell
- Second (staging) environment

When Tests are run and TestCafe starts, i get the following info

```
 Running tests in:
 - HeadlessChrome 99.0.4844 / Mac OS X 10.15.7

 Feature: Careers Page Available
(node:87344) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
```

I tried re-installing some packages, re-writing some of the steps, adding some flags to clear cache, change chrome port or similar, but nothing worked.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot investigate this issue without a complete example that we could run on our side. This example should contain all imported files and include the tested application's URL.

If you cannot disclose the test code and URL publicly, you can mail them to our Support Team at support@devexpress.com.

Comment: Hello @vasily.strelyaev.
I send the needed data to support@devexpress.com
Contact me if anything else is needed.

Comment: Thank you! Let's continue this discussion in the GitHub thread: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6948